# Perfect number recursion in SCHEME. (beginner)

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, perfect-numbers

Hey so I am creating a function (divides n), which is supposed to calculate the number of divisors in a number n with the help of a modulo function and a function that acts as a counter going down from the number n. My issue is that the modulo function should output a true or false depending on whether the number is whole however my if statement

```
(if (= (divides n k) #f)
    0
```

Im not sure why but the code wont evaluate the if statement as true or false.. it just skips it. Also im not sure that 0 should be the correct output I want it to just skip that number and not count it.

Heres my code:

```
(define (divides a b) (= 0 (modulo b a)))
(define (divisors-upto n k)
  (if (= (divides n k) #f)
      0
      (+ k (divisors-upto n (- k 1)))))
(define (divisors n) (divisors-upto n n))

(divisors 4) ;for example should produce the result 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by fixing the `divides` procedure, you reversed the arguments to `modulo`. This is how it should look:

```
(define (divides a b)
  (= 0 (modulo a b)))
```

The above tests if `b` divides `a`, that's how you're using it in the `divisors-upto` procedure. Also you should replace this:

```
(= (divides n k) #f)
```

With this:

```
(equal? (divides n k) #f)
```

Or even better, this:

```
(not (divides n k))
```

Apart from that, isn't this the same question that you [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379432/scheme-recursion-perfect-number-beginner-hopefully-easy-fix) before? I told you there that you're missing a case in the recursion, look at my previous answer in the link.

If it's not the same procedure, then I'm not really sure of what you want to do: in this question you state that the procedure "is supposed to calculate the number of divisors in a number", but that's not what the procedure is doing - you're adding the *actual divisors* (the `k` parameter in the procedure) and not the *number of divisors*. And again, you'd be missing a case - what happens if the current `k` is not a divisor? the recursion would exit prematurely! Try to work on this a bit, fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (divisors-upto n k)
  (cond ((zero? k)
         <???>) ; how many divisors are there if k is zero?
        ((not (divides n k))
         <???>) ; if k is not a divisor of n, we must proceed without incrementing
        (else   ; if k is a divisor of n, by how many should the count be incremented?
         (+ <???> (divisors-upto n (- k 1))))))
```

Comment: yea ive been working on this function a couple of ways thanks for the help ill give this a try

Comment: I've never thought of it this way, but now I see that you can define `not` simply as `(cut eq? #f <>)`. The idea of boolean comparison, in general, is so offensive to me that the whole idea has been fnorded out of my head. :-)

Comment: @Roark Great! and please don't forget to accept the answer that were most helpful for you in this and your other questions - just click on the check mark to their left.